# How can I fit text preciesly into a rectangular DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have a narrow rectangular Div that I'd like to render text into. Normally, it looks like this:
[image]

However, I'd like to maximize the size for readability, and as the text is to be dynamically provided, I stumbled upon [BigText](http://www.zachleat.com/web/bigtext-makes-text-big/), which gave me this:

[image]

It works perfectly for width, but ignores the height of the div entirely! How can I maximize the size of the text while staying within the `<DIV>`'s width *and* height?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q7gcb/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the `<b>` tag, and styled the `span` element with the following:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Lm76E/) - seems to be what you want (using `em`s it will work for all `font-size`s)

```
span {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -.5em;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: So setting the margin-top is what fixes the positioning? Excellent, thanks!

Comment: @RavenDreamer I am not really sure. There is `letter-spacing` which controls the horizontal spacing, but to my knowledge, there is nothing that controls the vertical spacing. The margin seems to do the trick, as it is `.6em` on the top/bottom of the element. Take a look at this animation. You will notice that the top is the same for all font sizes. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/SqLN4/ You will notice I use `.6em` in that example.. I think that is more percise, though you will not really notice when the font-size is smaller.

Comment: Between this answer and BigText, I believe I've got what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you set a `height` to your `.namebox` `div` element. If you leave that empty, the `div` will automatically become the size of the text. No need for any fancy stuff.

```
div.namebox
{
position:absolute;
background-color:Yellow;
text-align:center;
font-family:"Gabriola";
font-size: 50px;
top:27px;
left:22px;
width: 184px;
height: ;*------------0 height-------------------*/
z-index: -1; 
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7gcb/10/)

Comment: The problem with the solution is that I don't want the Div to be the height of the text; I want the text to be the height of the div *or smaller*. The Div needs to stay the same rectangle, I just want the text to change.

Comment: I see what you mean now. You wanted the text to fit perfectly snug within the yellow div; that's why he just moved it up. It's the creativity that makes this so much fun.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `height:inherit` instead of `height:38px` for class `div.namebox`.
`CSS` is as follows

```
div.namebox
{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:Yellow;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:"Gabriola";
    font-size: 50px;
    top:27px;
    left:22px;
    width: 184px;
    height: inherit;
    z-index: -1; 
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```